# Positioning divs at the bottom of container

Tags: html, css

I try to arrange elements in div, I want their bottom edges align bottom of div container (pink one). I tried to figure out something by myself, but I didn't came up with anything good.

```
    <div style="background: pink; display:block; height: 180px; float:left; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="background: lightgreen; display:block; float:left; text-align: left; margin: 0; padding:0; width: 36%;">
    dasas sasad asdasda<br/>
    dsda dsadasd dasdasd<br/>
    dddddddwwww www<br/>
    zzzzzzzzZaaaaaaaaa 
    </div>
    <div style="background: skyblue;  display:block; float:left;  text-align: left; margin: 0; padding:0; width: 39%; ">
    sssssss sssssddddd<br/>
   xccccccc<br/>
    aaaaaaaaa  vvvvvv
    </div>
    <div style="background: yellow; display:block; float:left; text-align: left; margin: 0; padding:0; width: 25%;">
    uuuuuuu uuuuuu<br/>
    zzzzzzz  ddddddd
    </div>
  </div>
```

here is js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Z3KvU/1/

and my attempts with display: inline-block; and vertical-align: bottom;

http://jsfiddle.net/H4EAT/

but results was far from expected

Thanks in advance for all suggestions
MTH

Comment: Please have mercy and do not write inline styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this style to the container:

```
display:flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
align-items: flex-end;
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wb6pa/)

[image]

See this awesome article about flexbox: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Please have mercy and do not write inline styles. Just because OP did it, you shouldn't follow the same mistake

Comment: @Ani I know inline styles are pain but in this case i needed to do it that way otherwise it would be deleted upon submit of code to webapp I'm working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using Jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3KvU/3/

```
$('.positioned').each(function() {
$(this).css({
    top: $(this).parent().innerHeight() - $(this).innerHeight() + 'px'
});
```

});

It's more compatible, although less cool.